# Titanium ios latest modules

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I want to know that ti.paypal and com.mirasense.scanditsdk latest module versions.
Now i am using ti.paypal (version 1.6.2) and com.mirasense.scanditsdk (version 1.1.1).
Is there any new versions are available so plz tell versions
and please download links too.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go here and see for yourself.On github they are constantly updating the code for modules

https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules

Thanks

Comment: Wahhab Bhai i checked from it all are updated but com.mirasense.scanditsdk module not found from here.